# How can I remove Header and Footer to all web pages when using Android WebView in Java?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using Android Webview to display a web page inside my application, I'm using Java. I'm not a very experienced programmer. My website is made with WordPress. In my Android App I would like to programmatically remove Header and Footer of all pages displayed in my app through the Android Webview.

If I check the ID of the header in my website, the ID is: `#meanmenu`
So I can remove it with CSS like so:

```
#meanmenu {
    display: none;
}
```

The Footer does not have an ID or Class but I can remove it with CSS like below:

```
footer {
    display: none;
}
```

How can I remove both the Header and Footer automatically when the pages load in my Webview?
Below is part of my Java code for the Webview:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class RentalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rentals);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("https://www.sample.com/pages");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [android webview without header and footer on page](https://walidashik.medium.com/android-webview-without-the-header-and-footer-of-webpage-64a66eb1ce7f).

Comment: @Alias Cartellano, thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @Alias Cartellano yeah, I managed to solve the issue, thank you.